# A question about graph coloring and partition of graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I got this question from professor, any hint would be helpful.

Let $k$ be a positive integer and let $X,Y$ be a partition of the vertex set of the graph $G$ such that $\chi(G[X])\le k$ and $\chi(G[Y])\le k$. 
Suppose $e(X,Y)\le k-1$. Then $\chi(G)\le k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3005578/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: My question when trying to answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005657/is-it-possible-to-start-with-a-partially-colored-graph-for-a-graph-g-and-compl